# Why am I getting this Passenger error Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I just created a new empty Rails app, it's almost empty. I created it just to try to pinpoint the problem, but I'm getting the following error.

I'm using Rails 3.1.0 and Ruby 1.9.2

```
Error message:
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
Exception class:
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
```

So I added rake-0.9.2.2 to the Gemfile and ran bundle and I'm still getting the same error message.

I have no idea what the problem is, I have even tried to open the rails log files but there is nothing in there.

I have tried many times to fix the error in different ways but nothing seems to work.

I'm thinking it could also have to do with something about the asset pipeline.

**ADDED DETAILS**

I tried packing the gems and now I got this

```
bundle show mysql2
/releases/20111117205618/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.10
bundle show rails
/releases/20111117205618/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.1.0
bundle show bundler
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21
```

Notice the difference between bundler gem and the other ones.

Comment: What happens when you type `rake` at CLI?

Comment: I've gotten that before.  If I remember correctly, it was because passenger couldn't load the gem bundle correctly.  Also, are you using rvm?

Comment: first, it said i had one pending migration, which confuses me because i had already ran cap deploy:migrations. then it complained about minitest gem being out of date, so i installed minitest gem and added it to my gem file in the test group. and then i run rake again and this is what i get "(RuntimeError)
`gem install minitest` and add `gem 'minitest' to you test helper."

Comment: ok, ran rake again and now gives me some successful tests and some failed tests

Comment: in the same production server i already have a rails app running. i dont want to touch that app right now. why does one app work and the other one doesnt?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I fixed the same error doing packing the gems into vendor/bundle like this:

From inside your app directory:

```
$ bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Give a shot and tell me if that works to you.

Comment: is it good enough for rvm? i guess it will just install all the gem in  global part of system or what ever you say ??? how to do it with gemset specific situation ????

Comment: Awesome! You save my life!

Comment: This made it worse for me

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem as well, fixed by following the instructions here: http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/the-path-to-better-rvm-and-passenger-integration

Comment: It is better to actually provide the steps here on StackOverflow because that site might go down, the owner might delete the post etc and thus in the future your answer will be a useless link to a 404 post. Or worse yet, the site might not be renewed by current owner and it will fall prey to malware authors and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem 'Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources' and found that my PATH did not include /usr/local/bin. After updating the PATH, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best answer/solution here is to add the following to your `deploy.rb` file (assuming Capistrano):

```
bundle install --deployment
```

You can also [read the full article and on other deployment engines](http://gembundler.com/deploying.html).