# Ruby on Rails Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created an app, have uploaded the app, which works locally and am getting a error. Can anyone tell me why? Or how to fix it?

the  error looks like this.

Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
Exception class:
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError

I'm am new to rails and am going to post some info I think will be helpful.

Here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'execjs'

gem 'therubyracer'
```

I have Rails 3.2.7,

I have RVM 1.14.12,

I have Ruby 1.9.3p194

Let me know if there is more information that I can post to better help answer this question.

Comment: Have you installed rake on your server? `gem install rake`

Comment: here's a solution to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173995/why-am-i-getting-this-passenger-error-could-not-find-rake-0-9-2-2-in-any-of-the