# Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2

While trying to update a rails app, where it required a new gem installed I got the following error when running my rails on the server (Apache2)

```
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

/home/server/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb    90  in `block in materialize'
1   /home/server/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb    83  in `map!'
2   /home/server/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb    83  in `materialize'
3   /home/server/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb  127 in `specs'
4   /home/server/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb  172 in `specs_for'
5   /home/server/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb  161 in `requested_specs'
6   /home/server/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb 23  in `requested_specs'
7   /home/server/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb 11  in `setup'
8   /home/server/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb 107 in `setup'
```

And when I do `bundle install`, or `gem list --local` it list the gems fine:

```
actionmailer (3.2.3)
actionpack (3.2.3)
activemodel (3.2.3)
activerecord (3.2.3)
activeresource (3.2.3)
activesupport (3.2.3)
arel (3.0.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.4)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
devise (2.1.2)
dynamic_form (1.1.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.3)
jquery-rails (2.0.2)
json (1.7.3)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.18)
multi_json (1.3.6)
orm_adapter (0.3.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.3)
railties (3.2.3)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
sass (3.1.19)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
sprockets (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uglifier (1.2.4)
warden (1.2.1)
```

But when I do ruby -v it says ruby 1.8.7, and error log says .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320...
How do I tell it to use the installed 1.8.7, as this has always worked (am not interested in upgrading)

I found this post -[[Why am I getting this Passenger error Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173995/why-am-i-getting-this-passenger-error-could-not-find-rake-0-9-2-2-in-any-of-the][1])

[1]: [Why am I getting this Passenger error Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173995/why-am-i-getting-this-passenger-error-could-not-find-rake-0-9-2-2-in-any-of-the) - Tried it with no success!

Comment: do rvm use 1.8.7 or rvm use 1.9.2 as required.

Comment: How do I tell it to use the installed 1.8.7 ? what does this means -- are you looking to use 1.8.7

Comment: Yes I would like to 1.8.7 - and it has worked with 1.8.7, but for some reason after modifying some files and changing the gem file and doing a bundle install it now wants to use 1.9.2 instead of 1.8.7

Comment: can u paste your Gemfile ,check for the version of rails in Gemfile.

Comment: also which version of rails are you interesed in using @jens jensen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make things simple, create a gemset

> rvm gemset first_app

- create a .rvmrc file in the project folder and enter rvm use 1.8.7@first_app

when you enter the project, check by entering,

ruby -v

rails -v

> rvm use first_app

Now do bundle install and then rails server, you should not get issues after this, reply back if any issues

Comment: I am now getting the following error: /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [bundler-1.1.4, rake-0.9.2.2, rubygems-bundler-1.0.3, rvm-1.11.3.5] (Gem::LoadError)
 from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
 from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
 from /usr/bin/rails:22

Comment: Got it working - needed to do a : bundle install --system, and rvm use system, and then it worked! Thanks @GhostRider!